# How to write conditions from the long output in ansible - I have to implement conditions for healthchecks

Tags: ansible

I have a health check command( Health check for port)
root@mahesh$ show port       ( This command will display the output like in the below)

### Slot/Port                    Type                 State

1/1                          ethernet             Up
2/1                          ethernet             Up
4/1                          ethernet             Up
5/1                          ethernet             Up
management                   ethernet             Up

in the above output State column needs to be always Up, If not I want to fail the task
How to implement such kind of condition.
I am aware of failed_when module but not getting idea , how to parse the output

Answer (score 0):

What type of device is this?  Have you looked to see if there was a [module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_network_modules.html)?

The status might also be in [ansible_facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variables-discovered-from-systems-facts).

I would look there first.